# openid connect stateless client as openid 2

Tags: openid, openid-connect

I am trying to understand how to migrate an **openid** server to an **openid connect** but while reading more about the **openid connect** flow, I notice that for the *clients* or *relay parties* things are now more complicated.

While in **openid** after performing the [discovery](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html), the exchange between *authentication server* from the client side, can be totally stateless (dumb mode), now with **openid connect** the client would need a `client_id` and a `client_secret` and some how store that information, this because of the [oauth2](http://oauth.net/2/) flow.

If I am right, this implies that every time an authentication needs to be made, a 'dynamic registration' will need to be performed in case the server / application doesn't have an `client_id` & `client_id`.

From my understanding, with **openid** an application in order to get access, can follow an stateless flow, and basically just **trust** the reply from the authentication server, simple as that, *no need to sign a contract first* to later trust as in  **openid connect** happens.

**openid** seems to be more versatile than **openid connect** but maybe I am totally wrong, therefore I would like to know any best practices about how to simplify the migration process. Or maybe just continue to use **openid** as always and consider **openid connect** as a totally different alternative.